# Prove that $DE>BC$

Tags: geometry

We choose two points outside triangle(on lines $AB,AC,BC$ means inside the triangle) $ABC$ on lines $AB,AC$ which are closer to $BC$ than $A$ Prove that $DE>BC$

[image]

We may apply triangle inequality but there is no good triangles to apply that first I thought drawing a parallel line that passes from one of $D,E$ and is parallel to $BC$ should work but it didn't.

Comment: First, try and prove that $BE > BC$. Then show that $DE > BE$.

Comment: "Closer to $BC$ than $A$" means $DB<AB$ and $EC<AC$?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг $BE>BC$ needs the triangle to be acute.

Comment: @velutluna No I don't mean so.

Comment: Then I don't think the statement you want to prove is true.

Comment: @velutluna Why do you think so?

Comment: Consider $A$ a very small angle, $B$ very far away from $A$, $C$ very close to $A$.

Comment: @velutluna But $D,E$ are outside the triangle.

Comment: @hellotinfish I see what you are saying.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг LOL I accidentally deleted my comment. Here's what I just said: It is not necessarily true that both $BE>BC$ and $DE>BE$. It may be thew case that $BE=BC$ or $DE=BE$, but it can't be the case that both equalities hold.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a very "thin" isosceles triangle $ADE$ (i.e., $\angle A$ is small). Pick $B\in AD$ very close to $A$ and $C\in AE$ very close to $E$. Then $BC\approx AE\ll DE$.

Answer (score 2):

Diagram below should clearly show why so many people believe what you want to prove is false. Unless we didn't understand what you mean.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Show that $BE\ge BC$ and $DE\ge BE$. If one of $BE>BC$ and $DE>BE$ is true, then we're done. Try to show some really absurd thing will happen if both $BE=BC$ and $DE=BE$. (Draw a circle centred at $B$ with radius$=BC$. $CE$ is its arc. Join $B$ and $E$. Draw another circle centred at $E$ with radius$=BE$). Join $C$ and $E$ with a straight line. Mark $D$ on the circle centred at $E$. Note that $D$ lies **below** $BE$. Then the straight lines $BD$ and $CE$ won't meet at $A$.)

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong.

Let $DE\perp AD$ and $C\equiv E$ (If you wish $E\rightarrow C$).

Thus, $DE<BC$.

Comment: But then $D$ will be inside the triangle(on $AB$)